# Deleting session variables in Safari causing errors

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have three variables in the $_SESSION array: "views", "user_id", and "username".  When a user logs out, "user_id" and "username" are deleted.  This works fine in all browsers, and in Safari about 75% of the time.  Sometimes, instead of deleting the variables, it just gives the value "deleted" to the variable.  This throws my whole site off because it's based on whether the variable is defined or not.

My code to delete the variables is:

```
unset($_SESSION["user_id"]);
unset($_SESSION["username"]);

$_SESSION = array();

session_destroy();
```

And in Safari, `var_dump($_SESSION)` gives:

```
...
["user_id"] => string(7) "deleted"
["username"] => string(7) "deleted"
...
```

Any ideas why Safari is doing this?

Comment: Why are you calling `session_destroy`? Just use `unset()` and that should do the trick. Maybe add a `session_write_close()` for good measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari has nothing to do with the problem. Sessions are managed on the server side and all Safari (or any browser) has to do with it is holding the cookie with the `PHPSESSID` inside.

Your problem is due to [session_destroy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). (emphasis mine)

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the
>   current session. ***It does not unset any of the global variables
>   associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.*** To use the
>   session variables again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

Your `unset()` call should do the trick by themselves. And you can combine them

```
unset($_SESSION["user_id"], $_SESSION["username"]);
```

Try adding `session_write_close();` and see if it makes a difference.

Failing that, try expiring the session cookie

```
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
);
```

Comment: So what are you suggesting he change? He's already using `unset()` before `session_destroy()`, what more does he have to do?

Comment: I removed the session_destroy() and the "$_SESSION = array(), and I also added a line to remove the PHPSESSID cookie. The problem still occurs. I should mention that immediately after deleting these variables, I navigate to another page which calls session_start() and re-creates the $_SESSION["Views"] variable. I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I thought maybe I'm starting the session before it has time to be deleted, If that's possible.

Comment: What's strange about this is your session data is stored on the server. So removing the data from `$_SESSION` should be all you need to do. You could always expire the cookie (edited answer to show how)

Comment: This, and i forgot to put the session_start() at the top of the file.  I accepted this answer.  Thank you!